# Can you set up a contingent order that only sells when the stock price falls to a value above the current price?

Tags: order-execution

For example, say the current price is $20 a share and I have sell order for when it hits $25 while decreasing in value. So the price will have to initially pass $25 without selling, but will sell if it hits $25 while dropping in price.

I'm sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, wasn't able to find anything when I searched.

Comment: The thing is that rise and fall can only be measured in terms "previously traded at a higher/lower price".  There is no "while dropping", there is only "has dropped".  It sounds like what you want is something like "if the price goes above $25 and then goes below $25, sell" (but maybe you actually want to set the threshold at $26 or something to try to increase the likelihood that you get in between $26 and your "real" target price of $25).  Is that sort of what you want?  (I don't know if such a thing is available.)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called stop-limit order

Comment: I appreciate your help but I think what I'm asking is more complicated than that. Suppose I buy a stock at $1 a share that I know will increase past $3 a share. The stock might continue to increase once it hits $3 or it might drop back down. What I want to do is have a contingency trade that is triggered if it suddenly starts to delta down towards a set amount still above my purchase price. So similar to a stop-limit, but with the additional feature that it only executes if a stock begins to drop significantly (but is still over the price at which I purchased it).

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you would quickly be stopped out at $3, anyway. A trade at $3.00 would activate your order; subsequent trades at $3.01 and $2.99 would stop you out. Remember, trades are executing all trading day long, every trading day.

Practically speaking, what you want is an automatic alert when the stock hits, say, $3.20. Then you can manually activate a $3 stop order or stop limit order.

Comment: It looks like your answer is referencing the numbers in the OP's comment on another answer, but that's confusing because different numbers were used in the question itself.  Maybe rephrase your answer in terms of the original question?